# How to order categorical string features in order of severity?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

If one of the features for my data set is a score that is categorical string like:

```
Score
X1c
X3a
X1a
X2b
X4
X1a
X1b
X4
```

Where `X1a` is the weakest followed by `X1b, X1c, X2a, X2b ...X4` with `X4` being the strongest, how can I encode it to integers such that `X1a` can be the lowest int and `X4` be the highest int. I'm looking to use a random forest classifier. Also, the training set is a separate data set so this encoding should be maintained for new data sets.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this task?

Comment: [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), which in scikit-learn is used for this very thing orders data alphabetically as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using rank:

```
df['Score_int'] = df.Score.rank(method='dense')
```

Output:

```
  Score  Score_int
0   X1c        3.0
1   X3a        5.0
2   X1a        1.0
3   X2b        4.0
4    X4        6.0
5   X1a        1.0
6   X1b        2.0
7    X4        6.0
```